# VSCode freezes when I save file

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-extensions

VS Code freezes when I save a file. I checked Developer Tools, but I don't know what extension or settings can cause this issue.

This issue occurs after some time during development on Next.js v13 project in dev mode. I run the project with default command `npm run dev` in VS Code terminal.

*I am not sure if it occurs after many hot reloads in Next.js. I will try to let running Next.js project for awhile and then chaning code if I can see the issue.*

I don't have this issue when I run a Vite project in dev mode.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot there is a message "Debugger attached". I am not sure what's that because I don't use VS Code debugger or an extension that uses VS Code debugger.

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: You can disable the extensions by clicking on the gear icon next to the extension and selecting "Disable" and then test again and see if the freeze persists

Comment: I would start by disabling the extensions that the popup is telling that it's using when saving the file

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida extension bisect is superior to that approach (log_2(n))

Comment: @user I edited my question to provide more context. Thanks, I didn't know about extension bisect. I have around 30 extensions and it occurs after 30mins-1hour only with Next.js project in dev mode. I will try to figure out if it occurs after many hot reloads in next.js

Comment: I came across [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38477) discussion and it seems like its because of GitLens extension. I will try to disable GitLens and will see.